# How do you create a table validated value set dependent on another value set?

Tags: oracle

How to create a table validated value set dependent on another value set?

Comment: This is very broad in nature. Can you please share the exact requirement, with the test data?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and apply the 'real person' test. What would the experienced SQL developer next to you say if you just asked the above question ? Do you believe you would get the answer you wanted ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `:$FLEX$`."Value set name" in the where condition. Read [the Oracle Apps documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/fnd/values20.htm).

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's question to indicate that they mean Oracle Apps. So if you're right this would count as a darn fine piece of deduction.

Comment: Question has a tag "oracle" that's why my answer was in the context of oracle apps